# Why is this giving error on using in built qsort

Tags: c++

I have written some piece of code which is giving me the error . The code is as follows :-

```
  long long int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
   {
     return ( *(long long int*)a - *(long long int*)b );
   }

 long long int number; 
 long long int *ar =(long long int *)(malloc(sizeof(long long int)*number));
 //Took the values of number and  ar from and then performed the following
 qsort(ar,number,sizeof(long long int),compare);
```

This code results into following error :-

`invalid conversion from long long int (*)(const void*, const void*)' to int (*)(const void*, const void*) initializing argument 4 of void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*, const void*))'`

what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
long long int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
```

to

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
```

Return value of this function is always int regardless type of your array.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my reply (and eq- in comments), simply changing the return type will make the program compile, but will cause error (i.e. wrong results) at runtime.

Comment: As clarified in parentheses, it will not cause run time errors, it will cause wrong results because it will simply truncate the return value to int - which may save the sign (which is the only important thing here), or it could just as well change it.

Comment: @Ritesh try this:
long long a[] = {0, 2147483649LL};
qsort(a, n, sizeof(a[0]), compare);
For me, this results in 2147483649 0 as the sorted sequence.

Comment: @IvanVergiliev - you were lucky. A bad comparison function can make `qsort` run off the end of the array, with nasty consequences.

Answer (score 5):

qsort expects a method with return type int, not long long.

And because straight forward casting to int might actually screw up your comparator function, you should probably do something like this (assuming you've already casted a and b to long long):

```
return a < b ? -1 : (a == b ? 0 : 1);
```

in order to conform to the requirements, i.e:

> The return value of this function should represent whether elem1 is
>   considered less than, equal to, or greater than elem2 by returning,
>   respectively, a negative value, zero or a positive value.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? Including on the correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

The 4th argument of `void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*, const void*))'` is a pointer to a function which signature is `int (*)(const void*, const void*))`.

You are giving it a function of signature `long long int (*)(const void*, const void*)`, which differs because its return type is not the right one, it should be an `int`.

Comment: so cant I do this for long long int ?

Comment: @Ritesh no you can't, probably because `qsort` is gonna use the result of your function, and it expects an int. Suppose your function returned a VERY LARGE number, which doesn't fit an int?

Comment: @Ritesh - yes, you can do this for `long long`. The **return type** of the function must be `int`, but the two arguments will be pointers to whatever type you passed to `qsort`, in this case `long long`.

Answer (score 2):

```
long long compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(long long*)a - *(long long*)b );
}
```

In addition to not being compatible with `qsort`, this type of comparison in general is only guaranteed to work with sufficiently small integers (or more generally, integers that are never too far apart). Prefer this way instead:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  long long rhs = *static_cast<const long long*>(a),
            lhs = *static_cast<const long long*>(b);
  return (rhs > lhs) - (lhs > rhs);
}
```

Comment: It's not about being small, it's about how far away the numbers are from each other - e.g. it will break if you compare something close to LLONG_MAX with something close to LLONG_MIN, because the difference will overflow.

Comment: @IvanVergiliev, yes (although small enough numbers will ensure that will never happen).

Comment: @eq- - since the question is tagged C++, the code needs a cast to convert the `const void*` arguments to `const long long*`.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, your function needs to return an int. The qsort function doesn't know the type of elements it sorts, hence the pointers to void in its signature. You need to return a value that is positive, when the left argument is bigger than the right one, zero when they are equal and a negative value when the left argument is smaller than the right one. You don't need to provide some exact answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
void qsort ( void * base, size_t num, size_t size, int ( * comparator ) ( const void *, const void * ) );
```

> Function that compares two elements. The function shall follow this
>   prototype:

```
int comparator ( const void * elem1, const void * elem2 );
```

turn function to

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
   {
     return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
   }
```

**cant I do this for long long int??**

> No,this function has contents same as the Standard C library header
>   `<stdlib.h>`.Only function signature has been replaced by two
>   declaration.(N3337/ § 25.5).

```
extern "C" void qsort(void* base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
int (*compar)(const void*, const void*));
extern "C++" void qsort(void* base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
int (*compar)(const void*, const void*));
```

**why should not return int while taking long long int.**

> The very time you do something like this `a=8589934592,b=4294967296;`
>   you will know it was better to declare a & b as
>   int.

Comment: Very bad advice (OP needs a `long long` compare function).

Comment: @Anonymous It worked for me even for long long int values by  just changing my return type to int

Comment: @Ritesh:- It will work till you don't do something like (5764607523034234880 - 9007199254740992) ....